# Git bash in Windows: change the default directory when opening mintty (pwd)

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, mintty

I am loosing a lot of time searching in internet for the following simple setting.

I installed git (and git bash) in Windows. What I want is just to open Git Bash and be in the directory I want. I don't want to change my home directory, just be in a given directory when I open the program.

More detailed, when I open Mingw / Git bash in Windows, I would like to be in the following folder:

`/c/blabla/my_git_repositories`

(this corresponds to the windows-style path: `C:\blabla\my_git_repositories`).

At the moment, I must write the following command **every time** I open GitBash:

`cd /c/blabla/my_git_repositories`

is this possible? Which file should i modify?
Actually the program is installed here:
`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want it happening every time you start an interactive shell, add

```
cd /c/blabla/my_git_repositories
```

to your shell startup. If your install includes the manpages say `man bash` and find the `INVOCATION` section, in a decent pager just `/^INV` will do it.  Or Google knows to interpret a search for `man bash` as a search for the bash manpage.

Windows doesn't ordinarily support shell logins at all so a lot of the shell's startup-circumstance detection is overkill on Windows. *Executing* it is extremely fast, but describing exactly how it decides takes a page or two.

The short form is, if the startup was told it's a login shell it reads the login startup files, including (your) `~/.bash_profile`, which generally should check for an interactive login and if so source the normal interactive shell startup `~/.bashrc`, so `~/.bash_profile` should end with something like

```
[[ $- = *i* && -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

and put whatever you want in `~/.bashrc`. That `cd`, set up your prompt colors, define your favorite shell aliases, add your personal scripts directory to `PATH`, whatever.

Comment: which file is exactly the "shell startup"?
I don't have  " ~/.bash_profile " file

Comment: Read all about it in the bash man page, the answer tells you how to find it and summarizes the bits you have to know, if you don't have a `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`  in your home dir then make one? Be sure to save it as ascii or utf-8, 16-bit character codes had their niche moment but it's past.

Comment: Thanks, i solved by changing the link and it's OK for now, in case I will need a more "stable" solution I will try this solution. PS I use only UTF-8 since many years, and hope that nobody will use other encodings, included the obsolete ASCII and of course 16-bit encodings.

Answer (score -1):

Partial solution when opening the program by clicking on a link.

Right click on the link → properties → Start in: set the value to "C:\blabla\my_git_repositories".

This will work only when you open the application from that link, but could be fine (depending by your needs).